# Extracting API into another heroku app. Best practice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rails-postgresql, heroku-postgres

I'm planning on extracting some API endpoints from a Rails app hosted on Heroku that uses Postgres into a new Heroku app. What is the advisable way to do this?

1. Share the database with the 2nd app and switch over API end points in my client side code?
2. Backup and migrate data to a new database using PG Backups?
3. Other?

Not sure if this is an opinion based question, but I'd appreciate some input.

Comment: Firstly, what is the context of the new app? I would only share the database if it needs to use the same data. If you need to use the schema, I'd just import the current to a new DB & iterate from there

Comment: It needs to use the same data.

Answer (score 0):

Both the options you've listed seem perfectly acceptable, but the decision is highly dependent on the nature of the API and what your consumers will be doing with it.

If the API is merely supplying data (i.e. read-only, with no endpoints for updating/creating new data), then I highly recommend creating a 'follower' postgres database, and having your API requests read from the follower. The two dbs are in synch, and you separate API traffic/load from regular app traffic/load.

Heroku's instructions for setting up a follower are here:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-follower-databases

If your API involves data updates/writes, then the decision to clone the db (vs) serving API and app from the same db is solely dependent on traffic volumes and your tolerance for managing two databases and keeping them synchronized.

On a side note, for your API endpoints, I **always** advise the use of ActiveModelSerializers or JBuilder for delivering data.

https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers